# JavaScript - What is wrong with my Hash Table?

Tags: javascript

I am doing the first problem on LeetCode, Two Sum. I am trying to do the problem using a hash table. This is what I came up with:

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  var hash = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var need = target - nums[i];
    if (!hash[need]) {
      hash[need] = i;
    } else {
      return [hash[nums[i]], i];
    }
  }  
};
```

When I run my code, I am getting undefined as an answer. Let's say I have an array `[2,3,1,6,4]` and my target is `8`. When I iterated through the array, I will get `8-2=6`, `8-3=5`, `8-1=7`, `8-6=2`, and `8-4=4`. So, my hash table should look like this according to my code:

`6:0
5:1
7:2
2:3
4:4`

If something is not in the hash table, I want to throw it into the hash. When I run into the number in the hash, then I return `hash[nums[i]]` and `i` since I am ready at the index and `hash[nums[i]]` has the value of the index that I need. I am unsure why I am getting an undefined. Any advice to make this better?

Comment: problem 1: every time you call `twoSum` you start with an empty `hash` array

Comment: You don't use a Hashmap. It is an ordinary array.

Comment: problem 2: as the `hash` array is empty, your loop will always have `!hash[need]` as true (because !undefined == true) ... so you'll fill the array with `nums.length` values, and return nothing (therefore return undefined)

Comment: Try to use an object instead an array: `var hash = {};`. This one can used like an hash map and must not been prefilled.

Comment: @Guybrush I created an object instead of an array for the hash and things worked out better. Now, I am trying to extract the index when the value and the needed adds up to the target. I don't know how to extract the key when the value added with the `need` equals target. I got the indices that I need, but I got something else added to it. Not sure how to make it better. This is my updated code:  https://repl.it/HSu0/1

Comment: I do not actually understand your code. Your updated code seems to make completely different things that your entire code.If you want a JavaScript solution for the LeetCode Two Sum problem, let us know.

Comment: My tip: Rethink your solution and have the problem to solve in mind. Sometimes, thinks get complicated when you have the wrong idea. The solution of the problem is up to 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code. I have removed the else part and returned the hash at end. Please let me know if this is what you were looking.

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  var hash = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    var need = target - nums[i];
    if (!hash[need]) {
      hash[need] = i;
    } 
  }
  return hash;
};

console.log(twoSum([2,3,1,6,4],8))
```

Comment: It is not quite I am looking for, but I managed to create a hash table using an object. Not sure if I can ask this, but can you give me feedback on how to make my code return only the indices when the two numbers add up to the value? Here is my updated code: https://repl.it/HSu0/1

Comment: Sorry Envo. Question is not clear and looks very different from what you originally asked. Suggest you post this as new question. Thanks.